# Flexibility of form

Tags: inequality

Prove that for all real $x,y,a,b$, one has
$$(5ax+ay+bx+3by)^2\leq(5a^2+2ab+3b^2)(5x^2+2xy+3y^2)$$

Here's my try but I can't continue.

$$(5ax+ay+bx+3by)^2=(\sqrt5a\cdot\sqrt5x+a\cdot y+b\cdot x+\sqrt3b\cdot\sqrt3y)^2\leq(5a^2+a^2+b^2+3b^2)(5x^2+y^2+x^2+3y^2)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality with respect to the inner product

$$\langle (x,y), (a,b)\rangle = 5ax+ay+bx+3by$$

Indeed,

$$
\begin{align*}
(5ax+ay+bx+3by)^2 &= \langle (x,y), (a,b)\rangle^2 \le \langle (x,y), (x,y)\rangle \langle(a,b),(a,b)\rangle\\
&= (5x^2+2xy+3y^2)(5a^2+2ab+3b^2)
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Reasonable. But as an inner product, it should be bilinear and positive-definite. How to guarantee that?

Comment: It is. Simply check it. @zhangwfjh

Answer (score 0):

By C-S we obtain:
$$(5a^2+2ab+3b^2)(5x^2+2xy+3y^2)=$$
$$=\left(5a^2+2ab+\frac{1}{5}b^2+\frac{14}{5}b^2\right)\left(5x^2+2xy+\frac{1}{5}y^2+\frac{14}{5}y^2\right)=$$
$$=\left(\left(\sqrt5a+\frac{1}{\sqrt5}b\right)^2+\frac{14}{5}b^2\right)\left(\left(\sqrt5x+\frac{1}{\sqrt5}y\right)^2+\frac{14}{5}y^2\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\left(\left(\sqrt5a+\frac{1}{\sqrt5}b\right)\left(\sqrt5x+\frac{1}{\sqrt5}y\right)+\frac{14}{5}by\right)^2=(5ax+ay+bx+3by)^2.$$
Done!